# Should we have a [light-ga] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Exactly as the title asks: should we have a [light-ga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-ga) tag for questions pertaining to aircraft with a maximum certificated takeoff wage of less than 12,500 pounds, and requiring only one crew member?

This is partially inspired by [my question about replacing the turn coordinator with a second horizon gyro](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/when-how-may-i-replace-the-turn-coordinator-with-an-artificial-horizon) (for which an Advisory Circular exists for Light GA, and where the requirements/regs are slightly different for Transport or Commuter category aircraft).
That sort of regulatory dichotomy exists in a lot of places, but is it significant enough to warrant a specific tag?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that we need that particular tag because regulations about light airplanes fall under other slightly more specific categories, like [far-part23](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-part23) or the appropriate regulatory authority (since certification questions could be different in different countries).  A question similar to the one that you linked to would depend on how the aircraft was certified anyway, so seems to be more appropriate.

On the other hand, if there is a certification question about *large* airplanes, then it should be tagged [far-part25](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-part25).

Also, not all light airplanes are GA either.  There are some airlines that use standard category airplanes in scheduled service.

Comment: The main issue is that there is a vast difference between corporate jets certificated under FAR 23 and your average Cessna single, which is what I think he's getting at.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Well, only *very* light jets are certified under Part 23.  Most are certified under Part 25 (and he did say "less than 12,500 lbs." which would include those "very light jets" that you refer to).

Comment: True -- in fact a better question probably is if we need a "commuter" category tag, which is more specialised IMO.